# Get directory from classpath (getting a file now)

Tags: java

I want to search for files in a directory. Therefore I want to get the directory in a File object but i'm getting a file instead of a directory. This is what I'm doing, it prints false but I want it to be true.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/strategy/viewconfigurations/");
File folder = new File(url.toString());
System.out.println(folder.isDirectory());
```

How can I load this way a directory?

Comment: Depending on how your application is bundled, a reference to a resource of this type might provide a reference to a zipped entry.  What protocol does `System.out.println(url)` display?

Comment: file:/C:/Users/.../Mission%20Control/target/classes/strategy/viewconfigurations/

Comment: That seems to point to a directory in an IDE project. What do you want to functionally achieve here? Do you perhaps want to read files from a folder that is bundled inside your application? If that is true then this is not a good strategy to follow; as soon as you package your application as a jar, what madProgrammer says becomes true; it will no longer be a directory on disk, it will be a path entry in a zip file.

Comment: It's currently in my project indeed, but it needs to be placed outside the jar. I just need to tell Maven to place this resource folder outside the jar. I'm running it now from Eclipse, and the file is in the target folder. It isn't zipped and I could easily open it from my file browser.

Comment: I can't post an answer yet, but I found the problem: the space in the folder name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems path or String you will got from the `URL` object cause problem.
You passed file path which you will got from the `url.toString()`.

You need to change below line

```
File folder = new File(url.toString());
```

with this line

```
File folder = new File(url.getPath());
```

You need path of that folder which will you get from `URL.getPath()` function.

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the space in the folder name and passing the path instead of the toString fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an alternative for Java 7+ to Yagnesh Agola's post for finding a directory from a classpath folder, you could you also the newer `java.nio.file.Path` class.

Here is an example:

```
URL outputXml = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("outputXml");
if(outputXml == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find path in classpath");
}
Path path = Paths.get(outputXml.toURI());
```